# What algorithm does Stack Overflow use to check subjectivity/objectivity?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

I have observed that Stack Overflow doesn't let you post questions which are subjective. Like if I have a keyword "question" it won't let me post this. So, I want to know a little bit about the algorithm Stack Overflow uses to check the subjectivity or objectivity of the question.

Comment: @0-60FPS 5 rep is needed first. Riya: I'm pretty sure it doesn't use a special algorithm to identify subjective posts. It's just a word blacklist.

Comment: There seems to be something missing in your question. You start your third sentence with "So, I want to know", There is nothing in the sentences before that, that warrants the use of "So". Please update your post, so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow doesn't have an *algorithm* for this; it just stops certain words (`question`, `problem`) from being used in titles. [Not everybody agrees with this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so), though; it's quite easy to work around. But as long as it keeps *some* bad questions from the site, and it's only a minor annoyance (e.g. try posting a question about the Halting Problem), the filter will stay.

Comment: Unless… *we* are the algorithm! (cue scary music)